# MongoDB & nodejs with Docker "MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms"

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I am using mongoDB with and NodeJS backend. I have Problem and the Problem have docker logs is below.

```
{ MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:897:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
     errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:897:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
#FROM node:10.12.0
FROM node:latest-alpline

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

This is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app_test
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo_test
    depends_on:
      - mongo_test
    networks:
      - nodeapp_network
  mongo_test:
    container_name: mongo_test
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - nodeapp_network
networks:
  nodeapp_network:
    driver: bridge
```

The following code connects mongodb to mongoose in node js:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo_test:27017/collectionName', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

I get the same result if I use localhost, 127.0.0.1, IP address instead of mongo_test.
I have consulted several blogs, stack overflows.
How can I do?

(ps. I can't well English, so Please understand even if words are awkward. Thank you.)

Comment: Using `localhost` inside a container refers to itself. If you want to access another service which is listening in a particular port, then you have to frame your URL like `http://<service-name>:<port>`.

Comment: @Thilak Does the service-name you say mean docker service?

Comment: Here `service-name` is nothing but `mongo_test`

Comment: make sure that your DB is up and running using one of thse methods : https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ , I think your app started before the DB

Comment: @Thilak If so, should it be in the form of "http://mongo_test:27017/collectionName" instead of "mongodb://mongo_test:27017/collectionName"?

Comment: @DOYEOPKIM As per the mongoose [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose#connecting-to-mongodb), in order to connect to a mongo DB, the url should be in `mongodb://localhost/my_database`.

Hence your URL to access mongo container would be `mongodb://mongo_test/my_database`.

Please update the `app.js` code in the question to have a better understanding.

**Reason**: Your error logs says that you are using `127.0.0.1` as hostname instead of `mongo_test` in mongo URL.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the current configuration, after few retries the app.js is connecting to the database

Here's what is happening:

- docker-compose is launching Mongodb service, the port is not yet open
- docker-compose starts app_test and app_test tries to connect it fails(2 to 3 times)
- After a few seconds, Mongodb port is now open on 27017
- Since your config has `restart: always` the node.js app restarts and connects successfully to the database

To avoid these restarts, you can write it like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
 try {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo_test:27017/collectionName', 
   { useNewUrlParser: true }
  );
 } catch (error) {
  console.log('Error connecting - retrying in 30 seconds')
}, 30000); // Wait for 30 seconds and try to connect again
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Explanation:

- The `connectTimeoutMS` is a MongoDB Connection Option and it sets the number of milliseconds a socket stays inactive before closing during the connection phase of the driver. That is to say, when the application initiates a connection, when a replica set connects to new members, or when a replica set reconnects to members. the default value is 30000 milliseconds would mean the driver would wait up to 3 seconds for a response from a MongoDB server. [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/reference/faq/)
- Compose does not wait until your `mongo_test` container is “ready”.
  The problem of waiting for a database to be ready is really just a subset of a much larger problem of distributed systems. In production, your database could become unavailable or move hosts at any time. Your application needs to be resilient to these types of failures. [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)
- Using `depends_on` in your `app_test` service is still no guarantee to establish the connection between your services.

##### Solution:

You can update your code to connect to MongoDB:

```
const connectWithRetry = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://mongo_test:27017/collectionName', {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log("succesfully connected to DB"))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    });
};

connectWithRetry();
```

Comment: default value is 30000 ms or 30 seconds actually, so this is not the problem for me as 30 seconds is plenty of time on my end.